# \Zend\Db\Sql\Sql where how to add expression?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db-table

I have some query when I need to add expresion to WHERE closure. I need this:

```
(column / ?) % 100 = 0
```

So I try this:

```
$where->and->equalTo(new Expression('(column / ?) % 100', $value), 0);
```

but this return error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Predicate Expression` instead.  Try this :

```
$where->addPredicate(new Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression('(column / ?) % 100 = 0',
                        $value));
```